# Java Desktop app with Ms Access

Tags: java, exception

My Db connection is error "`class not found exception`!". 
I want to show in java jTable with query result..

```
static Connection databaseConnection()throws ClassNotFoundException{
        Connection con=null;
        File file=new File("PlayDb/PlayIS.mdb");
        try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbcodbcDriver");
            con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver="+"{Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ="+file.getAbsoluteFile());
            System.out.print("Success con!!");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print("connection fail!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
   }
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. Please post your code. With a few notable exceptions most of us here aren't clairvoyant.

Answer (score 0):

If you can post full stacktrace, that would be easy to answer your question.
According to the description ( "class not found exception!" ) it looks like JVM can't load your JDBC driver.

Please post full stacktrace.

Did you set up "Data Source Name" correctly ?

Following tutorial how to how to setup "Data Source Name " and how to connect Java and MS Access database.
[An Overview of Java Database Connectivity](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/942641/An-Overview-of-Java-Database-Connectivity.htm)